# 2 way SSL crt and key in httr post R

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

I have a 2 way SSL API security : i am trying the below as per other links

In below function i input a json and URl of the API. It was working perfect before the 2 way SSL was implemented. After this 2 way SSL i tried the below :

```
get_pred_func = function(json_d,url) {
    
  certfile="..../cert.crt"
  
  keyfile='.../clnt.key'
    
    r <- content(POST(url, body =json_d, encode = "json", config( sslcert = certfile, sslkey = keyfile)))
    myDf <- as.data.frame(unlist(r))
    colnames(myDf)='response'
    myDf$id <- rownames(myDf) 
    final_df=spread(myDf,key = 'id',value = 'response')
    
    return(final_df)
     
  }
```

I keep getting the error when the file is stored there  :

```
Failed to get certificate location for .../cert.crt
```

what is the best way to use crt and key in post command in R?

Comment: What do the three / four dots in the variables `certfile` and `keyfile` mean? I have never seen such a path specification and strongly suspect this is the source of the error.

Comment: That's just for example. Didn't want to put the actual path. You can assume any example path for this example.

Comment: Well, the error specifically says that the path is wrong, so the path and working directory would be the first thing to inspect. Maybe use an absolute path, in case curl runs in another directory as R?

Comment: i am using an absolute path only to refer to the .crt and .key file. What i am unsure is does httr wrapper allow this? is the code structure i.e. config arguments correct broadly?

Comment: I tried the code above in Linux system and it works. it seems to be Windows OS issue.